# How is functor chaining done

Tags: haskell, functor

Hello i am reading Real World Haskell and i have stumbled upon this example from `Chapter 10 - Parsing a raw PGM file` where it explains how to eliminate boilerplate code using functor chaining:

```
(>>?) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
Nothing >>? _ = Nothing
Just v  >>? f = f v

-- L.ByteString -> Maybe (Int, L.ByteString)
getNat s = case L8.readInt s of
             Nothing -> Nothing
             Just (num,rest)
                 | num <= 0    -> Nothing
                 | otherwise -> Just (fromIntegral num, rest)

parseP5_take2 :: L.ByteString -> Maybe (Greymap, L.ByteString)
parseP5_take2 s =
    matchHeader (L8.pack "P5") s       >>?
    \s -> skipSpace ((), s)           >>?
    (getNat . snd)                    >>?
    skipSpace                         >>?
    \(width, s) ->   getNat s         >>?
    skipSpace                         >>?
    \(height, s) ->  getNat s         >>?
    \(maxGrey, s) -> getBytes 1 s     >>?
    (getBytes (width * height) . snd) >>?
    \(bitmap, s) -> Just (Greymap width height maxGrey bitmap, s)

skipSpace :: (a, L.ByteString) -> Maybe (a, L.ByteString)
skipSpace (a, s) = Just (a, L8.dropWhile isSpace s)
```

I do not understand the following: If the `>>?` operator takes a `Maybe a` and applies a method but returns a `Maybe b` then how come the `skipSpace` and `getNat` fit in since both accept an unboxed (non-maybe) `argument`.
So you have a `Maybe a` and you pass it through a `>>?` ,it means you will have a `Maybe b`...when is this `Maybe b` unboxed to be given to the next method ? ( in our case `getNat` or `skipSpace` ?

What i mean is that after each `>>?` and before each method what you have is a `Maybe something` ,while the next method is of type  `nextmethod::something->Maybe somethingElse`. When is the `Maybe something` unboxed into `something` for the method that uses it ?

`method_0   >>? [Maybe something]    method_1 >>? [Maybe somethingElse]  method_2`

So in the `[ ]` i have written the types that result from `>>?` just before being given to the methods.
`method_1` accepts a `something` while `method_2` accepts a `somethingElse`. Who does the unboxing for these 2 methods?

Comment: Because, the `>>?` operator "unboxes" the value. It does not call `f` on the `Maybe a` value, but on `v` which is "unwrapped" out of the `Just` constructor.

Comment: This is a motivating example for monads (which are introduced in chapter 14; this example comes from chapter 10), since `(>>?) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b` is just `(>>?) = (>>=)`, a restriction of the general bind operator to the `Maybe` type class.

Comment: This indeed taken from `chapter 10` but what confuses me is that the `>>?` does not return the unboxed value but returns still a `boxed` value.So the next method that uses the result has to somehow unbox it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach to explain why `>>?` is useful.

If these were ordinary functions of type `a -> b`, we could just chain them together using function composition.

```
f :: a -> b
g :: b -> c
h :: c -> d

h . g . f :: a -> d
```

Or introducing a new operator `f >>> g = g . f` as "reverse composition",

```
f >>> g >>> h :: a -> d
```

However, the `Maybe` complicates things, because now the return type of one function does not match the input of the next:

```
f' :: a -> Maybe b
g' :: b -> Maybe c
h' :: c -> Maybe d

f' >>> g' >>> h'  -- type check errors
```

However, since `Maybe` is a functor, we can use `fmap` to apply `g'` to the return value of `f'`.

```
x :: a
f' x :: Maybe b
fmap g' (f' x) :: Maybe (Maybe c)
fmap h' (fmap g' (f' x)) :: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe d))
```

But the more we do this, the more the wrappers pile up; eventually, we need to try to get the value of type `d` out from under all the wrappers.

Certain functors allow us to write a function I'll call `join` that "reduces" a layer of wrappers by "joining" them together. `Maybe` is one of those functors:

```
join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join Nothing = Nothing
join (Just Nothing) = Nothing
join (Just (Just x)) = Just x
```

Here, if both wrappers are `Just`, we eliminate one. If `Nothing` appears in the pile at all, we return `Nothing. Now, we could write our chained function like

```
fmap g' (f' x) :: Maybe (Maybe c)
join (fmap g' (f' x)) :: Maybe c
fmap h' (join (fmap g' (f' x))) :: Maybe (Maybe d)
join (fmap h' (join (fmap g' (f' x)))) :: Maybe d
```

That's still a bit of boiler plate, but notice that after each call to `fmap`,
we call `join` on the return value. We can abstract that away using a new operator `>>?`, which simply maps its right-hand operand over the left-hand operand, then reduces the result.

```
>>? :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
m >>? f = join (fmap f m)
```

Using the new operator, we can simplify the long chain of calls to `fmap` and `join` to

```
f' x >>? g' >>? h'
```

It should be easy enough to convince yourself that  `Just (f' x) == fmap f' (Just x)`, so we can further smooth our chain out to look like

```
Just x >>? f' >>? g' >>? h'
```

which now looks a *lot* more like our original composition.

---

When you read Chapter 14 and learn about monads, you'll discover that monads are just the special functors, like `Maybe`, for which you can implement `join`. Further, though here we defined `>>?` in terms of `join`, the convention in Haskell is to define `>>=` (`??>` for *any* monad, not just `Maybe`) directly and then define `join` in terms of `>>=`. With `Maybe`, that looks like

```
>>? :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
Nothing >>? _ = Nothing
(Just x) >>? f = f x

join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
join m = m >>? id
-- join Nothing = Nothing >>? id = Nothing
-- join (Just Nothing) = (Just Nothing) >>? id = id Nothing = Nothing
-- join (Just (Just x)) = (Just (Just x)) >>? id = id (Just x) = Just x
```

Answer (score 2):

`(>>?)` is an *infix* operator. When used as such, it takes a `Maybe a` on the left-hand side, and a `(a -> Maybe b)` function on the right-hand side.

`getNat` fits the right-hand side because it has the type `L.ByteString -> Maybe (Int, L.ByteString)`. Here, `a` is `L.ByteString`, and `b` is `(Int, L.ByteString)`.

`skipSpace` also fits the right-hand side of `(>>?)`. Here, `a` is `(a1, L.ByteString)`, and `b` is `(a1, L.ByteString)`. (I renamed the type argument in the function to `a1` as to not confuse it with the `a` and `b` from the `(>>?)` type definition.

Since the return value of the `(>>?)` operator is `Maybe b`, you can keep chaining the return value with more `(>>?)` operators, which is what the example does; it just breaks that chain over multiple lines.

Comment: But you just said that `>>?` returns a `Maybe b` and `getNat` takes a `L.ByteString` and not a `Maybe L.ByteString`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: but your `getNat` does *not* get the result of the `>>?`, it is the "second operand".

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Yes, but when you compose the return value with `>>? getNat`, then `getNat` sits on the right-hand side of the operator.